# Unvalidated redirect whitelisting filter / other already implemented in Java?

Tags: java, servlet-filters, whitelist, owasp

I'm working on reducing our site's exploitability wrt OWasp unvalidated redirects (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A10-Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards).  We're using a pretty standard Spring MVC + Hibernate + JSP + mysql + Java stack.

Since owasp says this is in their top ten, I imagine it's a common issue, so I thought Spring or someone would already have a whitelisting filter, or maybe apache would have a whitelisting wrapper for HttpServletRequest, but I cannot seem to find such a thing.

Trying to avoid re-inventing the wheel, and just want to ask the stack community if anyone knows if this has been done and is available at this time, or if I should just roll my own.

Thanks for any info